# Please explain me this...I'm stuck

Tags: c

I've started doing c and of late I've started doing the c programming book by dennis ritchie and brian kernighan... I'm stuck with the exercise 1.9 "**write a c program to copy its input to its output,replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank**"... I've tried many ways... looked upon internet and found answers but no explanation...
I've seen a code that looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c, last;
    last = EOF;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
    if (c != ' ')
        putchar(c);
    if (c == ' ') 
        {
        if (last != ' ')
        putchar(c);
        }
    last = c;
    }
}
```

so please somebody explain this or give me another code with proper explanation

Thank you

Comment: Figure it out. It's right there in front of you. Read it. Do you know what "if" means? No? Look it up. Don't know what "!=" means? Look it up. Walk through the logic with pencil and paper, breaking it down into the smallest pieces you can -- that's how it's done. Don't try to digest it all at once, break it down. You'll never find an easier example than this.

Comment: Surely will follow what you've said sir... Thank you

Comment: Write down an example string on paper -- `"foo   bar baz"` for example -- and walk through what the code does with that string. For each statement, for each iteration of the loop, write out one line with the values of all the variables at that point. Columns of changing values marching down the page. After 30+ years, once in a while I *still* do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c, last;
    last = EOF;

    /* while we get a char that isn't EOF */
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        /* if it's not a space, print it */
        if (c != ' ')
            putchar(c);
        /* otherwise, if the previous char was not a space, print it */
        if (c == ' ') 
            if (last != ' ')
                putchar(c);
        last = c;
    }
}
```

This code can be written more simply as

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c, last;

    /* while we get a char that isn't EOF */
    for (last = EOF; (c = getchar()) != EOF; last = c) {
        /* if it's not a space, print it */
        if (c != ' ')
            putchar(c);
        /* otherwise, if the previous char was not a space, print it */
        else
            if (last != ' ')
                putchar(c);
    }
}
```